# Table View Pagination with fetch data from api swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i'm trying to make a table view with a data from api call , i have a question :

im trying to make my table view when scroll refresh and make the api call fetch data append it to table view data , im using table view refresh controller but it's work when scroll down or at the top i need to make this happening in the opposite way ? when scroll at the bottom of the table view call this refresh method to fetch data and make table view work with pagination :

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
//        self.usersTable.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI))
        logo.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        self.usersTable.dataSource = self
        self.usersTable.register(UINib(nibName: "UserCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "USERCELL")
        checkData()
        self.usersTable.refreshControl = refreshControl
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    @objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
       
        populateUsers(page:page)
        page = page + 1
       
    }
```

here's my refresh method

and her's my api call and fetching data :

```
 private func populateUsers(page:Int){
       
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users?since=\(page)") else {
            
            fatalError("url was incorrect! ")
        }
        
        let resource = Resource<Users>(url: url)
        
        Webservice().getData(resource: resource, completion: { [self] result in
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let users):
                users.forEach { (user) in
                    let user1 = UserInfo(context:self.context)
                    user1.id = Int32(user.id)
                    user1.login = user.login
                    self.users.append(user1)
                    if page == 0 {

                    }
                    saveUsers()
                    self.usersTable.reloadData()
                }
                print (users)
            
            case .failure(let error):
                print (error.localizedDescription)
            
            }
        })
    }
```

and i also sometimes the cell repeated ! can any body help me to make this work better and in more professional way please

Answer (score 0):

You can prefetch the cells datasource before it is displayed and load data on it, refer to this link:
https://medium.com/monstar-lab-bangladesh-engineering/tableview-prefetching-datasource-3de593530c4a